# how to create helm chart of postgres with pvc

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I would like to create a helm chart for PostgreSQL with PVC (persistent volume claim).

I've looked at trying katacoda https://www.katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes/helm-package-manager
Create Postgres helm chart with pvc.

How might I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As we can read from [PostgreSQL](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/postgresql) helm charts docs it can be used with following [parameters](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql/#parameters):

```
+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
|         Parameter          |                           Description                           |    Default    |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| persistence.enabled        | Enable data persistence                                         | true          |
| persistence.existingClaim  | Use a existing PVC which must be created manually before bound  | nil           |
| persistence.storageClass   | Specify the storageClass used to provision the volume           | nil           |
| persistence.mountPath      | Path to mount data volume at                                    | nil           |
| persistence.accessMode     | Access mode of data volume                                      | ReadWriteOnce |
| persistence.size           | Size of data volume                                             | 8Gi           |
| persistence.annotations    | Persistent Volume Claim annotations                             | {}            |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

> ### Persistence
>
> The data is persisted by default using PVC templates in the PostgreSQL statefulset. You can disable the persistence setting the  `persistence.enabled`  parameter to  `false`. A default  `StorageClass`  is needed in the Kubernetes cluster to dynamically provision the volumes. Specify another StorageClass in the  `persistence.storageClass`  or set  `persistence.existingClaim`  if you have already existing persistent volumes to use.

This means you just need to create your own [Persistent Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) which can for example look like this:

*pv.yaml*

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

*pvc.yaml*

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
```

Once those are deployed and bounded you can install the PostgreSQL chart:

`helm install my-release bitnami/postgresql --set persistence.existingClaim=task-pv-claim`

Comment: what is type: local in pv.yaml? why we need this?

Answer (score 6):

I deployed using following `PVC` ,`values.yaml` and Chart.yaml

pvc.yaml

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 25Gi
```

values.yaml

```
postgresql:
  cpu: 1000m
  memory: 1Gi
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    existingClaim: postgres-pvc
  volumePermissions:
    enabled: true
  replication:
    enabled: false
  initdbScripts:
    psql.sql: |
      CREATE USER user WITH PASSWORD 'pass';
      ALTER USER user WITH SUPERUSER;
```

Chart.yaml

```
apiVersion: v2
name: pgname
description: A Short description

type: application

version: 0.1.3

appVersion: 1.16.2

dependencies:
  - name: postgresql
    version: 7.x.x
    repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
    condition: postgresql.enabled
    tags:
      - services
      - db
      - write
```

I have got above files in following directory structure.

```
.
├── Chart.yaml
├── charts
│   └── postgresql-7.7.3.tgz
└── values.yaml
```

At `.` I do `helm dependency update` and `helm install release_name .` to install. Before that `kubectl apply -f pvc.yaml`

***Note*** You Need to in in same namespace

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried to run kubectl apply -f chat.yaml but its showing error,
error: unable to decode "chart.yaml": Object 'Kind' is missing

Comment: i am able to create pvc using kubectl apply -f pvc.yaml command, when i run below command i am getting  function "ternary" not defined error.

cmd=helm install demo stable/postgresql --set persistence.storageClass=postgres-pvc

error=Error: parse error in "postgresql/templates/statefulset.yaml": template: postgresql/templates/statefulset.yaml:85: function "ternary" not defined

Answer (score 1):

this https://arctype.com/blog/deploy-postgres-kubernetes/ solve my issues

```
# clean
helm list
helm delete postgresql-db
helm repo remove bitnami
kubectl get pvc
kubectl delete pvc data-postgresql-db
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm search repo postgresql

# Create PV & PVC
echo "---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgresql-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
" > pv.yaml
k apply -f pv.yaml

echo "---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgresql-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
" > pvc.yaml
k apply -f pvc.yaml

helm install postgresql-db bitnami/postgresql --set persistence.existingClaim=postgresql-pv-claim --set volumePermissions.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Only with these parameters will work.

helm install  bitnami/postgresql --set primary.persistence.enabled=true --set primary.persistence.existingClaim=postgres-pv-claim --set primary.persistence.storageClass= --set volumePermissions.enabled=true